# ionic select alert interface not showing up at all

Tags: ionic-framework

i have simple html modal created with select and date field, but not able to see alert or action sheet interface when opened modal form

below is the html code

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet">
        <ion-option value="f" selected="true">Female</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

i am getting output as below, showing both the values instead of dropdown.

[image]

what is missing in my code.

Comment: You are developing in ionic 2?

Comment: "version": "1.3.3",

Comment: For gender you need select box?

Comment: yes, also it works correctly if i update html and use select in place of ion-select and option in place of ion-option